# casperjs.download() with Jenkins on Ubuntu does not work

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, jenkins, ant, casperjs

I have a problem downloading files with casperjs.
The script is working well, but only running on windows (Jenkins and CLI) or on Ubuntu only on the command-line.

When I want to start the script with Jenkins (running on Ubuntu), and the result is malformed but successfully (test-result). **The files are not downloaded.**

**Windows 64 Bit:**

- Jenkins (version 2.121.1)

  - running independent.
- Casperjs Version 1.1.4
- Phantomjs version 2.1.1
- ANT version 1.10.3

**Ubuntu 18.04 LTS:**

- Jenkins (version 2.131)

  - running on Apache Tomcat (version 8.0.53).
- Casperjs Version 1.1.4
- Phantomjs version 2.1.1
- ANT version 1.10.3

Download function:

```
 function downloadFile(obj) {
     try {
         casper.test.assertExists(x(obj.id));
         var fs = require('fs'),
             filename = casper.getElementInfo(x(obj.id + "/strong"))
             .html;
         casper.download(casper.getElementInfo(x(obj.id))
             .attributes.href, fs.workingDirectory + '/downloads/' + filename);
     } catch (e) {
        casper.test.fail(e);
    }
 }
```

Passed object:

```
 {
      'type': 'downloadFile',
      'id': 'id("content-main")/div[1]/a[1]'
 }
```

Jenkins (Ubuntu):

```
[exec] [32;1mPASS[0m Find an element matching: xpath selector: id("content-main")/div[1]/a[1]
```

Jenkins (Windows):

```
 [exec] PASS Find an element matching: xpath selector: id("content-main")/div[1]/a[1]
```

CLI(Windows & Ubuntu):

```
 PASS Find an element matching: xpath selector: id("content-main")/div[1]/a[1]
```

Do you have any idea?
There is no error-message or any hint...

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: On Windows and in the CLI (Windows&Ubuntu) the files are downloaded